# Redirect website.com/path to website.it/path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a website, developed in Joomla and hosted in my VPS, with a domain like website.it. Recently, I bought a domain website.com with redirect service, so, if you write website.com, you are redirect to website.it, and this is ok.

But how can I do if I want that, for example, website**.com**/contacts (that now leads to 404 error page) leads to website.**it**/contacts?
Can i do it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*website\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.it/$1 [R=301,L]
```